# Symfony2 session idle notification

Tags: symfony

I want to implement session idle notification feature. If user hasn't done any activity for period X when dialog message should be provided with question `Do you want to extend your session?`

My algorithm looks like:

1. KernelEventListener which check wether user is idle for too long (should be logged out);
2. AJAX action (`/idle`) which checks wether user should be notified that he will be logged out soon;
3. Javascript function which does recurring ajax calls to `/idle` action & does some actions based on response;

So far I've done everything except part which checks whether user is idle for given time (2).

Symfony2 Session has *MetadadataBag* with *lastUsed()* method. I'm using it in *KernelEventListener*. my code looks like:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class SessionIdleHandler
{

    protected $session;
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $router;
    protected $maxIdleTime;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, RouterInterface $router, $maxIdleTime = 0)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->maxIdleTime = $maxIdleTime;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->maxIdleTime > 0) {
            $this->session->start();;
            $lapse = time() - $this->session->getMetadataBag()->getLastUsed();

            if ($lapse > $this->maxIdleTime) {
                $this->securityContext->setToken(null);
                $this->session->getFlashBag()->set('info', 'You have been logged out due to inactivity.');

                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('user_login')));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller action:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * Class DefaultController
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * 
     * checks whether User Session is IDLE. If so - notify else logout
     * 
     * @Route("/idle", name="idle")
     */
    public function autoLogoutAction()
    {
        $service = $this->get('session_idle.service');
        $idleTime = $this->container->getParameter('session_notify_idle_time');

        $response = new \stdClass();
        $response->expired = false;

        if ($service->hasExpired()) {
            $response->expired = true;
            $service->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set('info', 'You have been logged out due to inactivity.');
        } else if ($serive->needNotification()) {
            $response->expired = false;
            $response->message =  sprintf(
                'Your session will expire in %d minutes', 
                $service->getExpirationTime()
            );   
        }

        return JsonResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Problem which I'm facing - on every http request when contructing Session object -> *lastUsed* time changes.

**Is it possible to skip lastUsed update during request?**

Maybe it's possible to change it's behaviour in HttpKernelEvent? Also are there any other solutions?

Comment: Why don't you maintain your own `DateTime` object and check for expiration?

Comment: @JovanPerovic because Symfony2 has functionality which I need and don't want to implement same again. That's why I'm thinking how to solve problema using sf2 functionality.